# Accessing a javabean from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I've a session bean with some string properties.

How could I access it and its properties from a jsp page, checking if one of them is equal or not to a given string?

I think I've to use `<c:choose>` and `<bean:write>` tag, but how? An example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<c:if test="${beanName.beanProp == 'the string'}">
  It's equal.
</c:if>
```

Comment: Perfect, I've used `test="${beanName.beanProp == 'the string'}"` in a `<c:when>` tag and it works. Thanks.